# Como imprimo un valor fuera de Foreach y conservo ese valor con $_SESSION

Tags: php, array, session, foreach

Actualmente tengo el siguiente codigo PHP insertado en una etiqueta HTML de esta manera:

```
<div class="string">
   <code>

   <php?
    $string= $_POST["string_url"];
    parse_str($string,$my_array);
    foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
      echo "$key => $value<br>";
    }

    ?>
    </code>
    </div>
```

Ese script lo utilizare para extraer los parametros de una URL, lo que busco es poder imprimir el resultado de `echo "$key => $value<br>";`fuera del Foreach en una sola variable y aparte agregarle una `$_SESSION['extraccion'];` para no perder el valor cuando se refresque la pagina.php

Busco obtener algo asi, que el script me permita imprimir el resultado fuera del Foreach

```
<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
     session_start();

     $string= $_POST["string_url"];
     parse_str($string,$my_array);
     foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){

     $extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
     $_SESSION['extraccion '] = $extraccion;

     }
```

Y el resultado insertarlo en una etiqueta HTML dentro de una `$_SESSION` para no perder el valor al refrescar la pagina

```
<div class="string">
      <code>
      <php? echo $_SESSION['extraccion']; ?>
      </code>
</div>
```

El problema esta en que la variable `$_SESSION['extraccion'];` solo me imprime el ultimo valor del array. Pero si me conserva la SESSION al resfrescar la pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece haberte entendido que tu problema es que únicamente te guarda el último valor del array:

```
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
    $extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
    $_SESSION['extraccion'] = $extraccion;
}
```

Y eso te sucede porque es lo que le estás pidiendo: `$_SESSION` es un array y estás guardando el resultado de cada iteración en el mismo elemento `extraccion`. Generando nuevos elementos en el array lo resuelves.

Prueba así:

```
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
    $extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
    $_SESSION['extraccion'][$key] = $extraccion;
}
```

O incluso así:

```
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
    $extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
    $_SESSION['extraccion'][] = $extraccion;
}
```

Para mostrar su contenido en el HTML, puedes usar `implode()`:

```
<div class="string">
      <code>
      <php? echo implode(' ',$_SESSION['extraccion']); ?>
      </code>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Estaba probando el algoritmo y resulta que cada vez que introdusco un valor en `$string= $_POST["string_url"];` se me van sumando los valores viejos los recientes. Lo que quiero es que cuando refresque la pagina se muestre el array recientemente tomado y cuando genere un string me muestre solamente el nuevo sin ir sumandose.. Saludos

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres conseguir, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo con datos para ilustrarlo? Igual es mejor plantear una nueva pregunta para dejar esta cerrada. Déjame aquí el enlace para localizarla

Comment: Buenas, actualizo el comentario. Lo que busco ahora es que se imprima un solo elemento del Array. Cuando hago la consulta se almacena dentro  `$string= $_POST["string_url"];` la siguiente variable `$string = https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?perfil=12345678~&imagen=123456&calidad=1080p&encoder=-zMfiy24~~`, se imprime perfecto, el problema està en que cuando vuelvo a hacer una consulta de una URL distinta a la anterior, se almacena un nuevo elemento dentro del Array mostrandome el resultado nuevo y el anterior.

Comment: Sigo sin entender lo que pides. ¿Podrías ampliar la pregunta o hacer una nueva mostrando qué te gustaría obtener? Mostrando lo que se imprime y lo que quieres que se imprima, lo que se almacena y lo que quieres que se almacene...

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366781/como-imprimo-un-solo-elemento-del-array-en-php Aqui realice una nueva pregunta y bien explicada.