# Como imprimo la última consulta del Array en $_SESSION

Tags: php, array, php5, foreach

Busco imprimir la variable `$string` con la funcion de `parse_str` en un Array, ademas utilizo `$_SESSION` para almacenar el resultado por si la pagina.php se llegase a refrescar se mantenga el resultado.

```
    $string = $_POST['url'];
    //$string = "https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?perfil=12345678~&imagen=123456&calidad=1080p&encoder=-zMfiy24~~";
    parse_str($string,$my_array);
    foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
    $extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
    $_SESSION['extraccion'][$key] = $extraccion;
```

La variable `$string = "https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?perfil=12345678~&imagen=123456&calidad=1080p&encoder=-zMfiy24~~";` almacenaria esta cadena y se imprime de esta forma:

```
<div class="string">
      <php? echo implode(' ',$_SESSION['extraccion']); ?>
</div>
```

Obteniendo asi el siguiente resultado:

```
https://sub1_dominio_com/pagina_php?perfil => 12345678~
imagen => 123456
calidad => 1080p
encoder => -zMfiy24~~
```

El problema está en que cuando consulto una URL distinta a la anterior se imprime el nuevo resultado junto al anterior y asi sucesivamente sin parar, viendose de esta manera:

```
https://sub1_dominio_com/pagina_php?perfil => 12345678~
imagen => 123456
calidad => 1080p
encoder => -zMfiy24~~
https://sub1_dominio_com/pagina_php?perfil => 87654321~
imagen => 654321
calidad => 720p
encoder => -xGery24d~
```

Lo que quiero es que siempre se imprima y almacene en `$_SESSION` únicamente la última consulta cada vez que haga una nueva.

Saludos

Comment: No entiendo del todo la pregunta. ¿Te interesa guardar la información anterior o no? Creo que saber ese detalle es clave para una respuesta óptima.

Comment: No, cómo explico, solo quiero guardar la información nueva y que se muestre esa.n

Comment: Corregí la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: En ese caso actualiza el dato en la variable de sesión y listo. Y para mostrarlo lo sacas directamente sin usar `foreach`

Comment: No entendi bien, podrias dar un ejemplo ilustrado por favor?

Comment: Si el dato se guarda aquí por ejemplo: `$_SESSION['extraccion']` y te interesa un solo dato, puedes guardarlo direcamente así: `$_SESSION['extraccion'] = "El dato a guardar";` y cuando lo necesites, para mostrarlo, lo sacas directamente mediante algo así más o menos: `echo $_SESSION['extraccion'];` No veo la necesidad de leerlo mediante un `foreach` ¿?

Comment: Realmente no sé útil ya que el script consiste en imprimir todos los parámetros de una dirección URL en un Array.

Comment: Entonces no entiendo, en un comentario anterior dijiste que solamente interesa guarda la última, ahora dices que interesa guardar/mostrar todas ¿?  Eso es precisamente lo que hace el código, entonces no entiendo cuál es el problema.

Comment: Cómo que no leíste el cuerpo de la pregunta. Cuando digo mostrar todo me estoy refiriendo a mostrar todos los parámetros del string. La cosa es que cuándo consulto otra cadena se imprime y se muestra también la consulta anterior, vuelvo a hacer otra consulta se imprime la nueva consulta y se mostrarían las dos cadenas anteriores y así sucesivamente..

Comment: La pregunta está planteada de una forma algo confusa. Sugiero que describas brevemente en un párrafo cuál es el problema y luego muestras el código y todo lo que quieras. He leído la pregunta y no entiendo en sí ni lo que quieres ni qué problema en concreto tienes. Muchas veces el principal problema es no saber explicar el problema.

Answer (score 1):

podrias intentar destruir la session usando la funcion `session_destroy` o limpiando la session usando la funcion `session_unset` antes de consultar una nueva URL . Para mas informacion te dejo 2 enlaces referente a session en PHP

(session_destroy) [https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php]

(session_unset) [https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-unset.php]

Answer (score 0):

Entre estas líneas:

```
$extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
$_SESSION['extraccion'][$key] = $extraccion;
```

Añade lo siguiente:

```
$extraccion = "$key => $value<br>";
$_SESSION['extraccion'] = array();
$_SESSION['extraccion'][$key] = $extraccion;
```

Con eso reinicias el arreglo cada vez asignándole un arreglo vacío

Comment: Hola, probe la siguiente estructura y eso me imprime un elemento a medias, es decir se logra visualizar una parte del parametros,por ejemplo: `imagen => 123456`